# while closing jquery thickbox jquery image slider is giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Thickbox 3.1(by cody lindley) in my asp.net application. While closing thickbox I am getting jquery error from file "jQuery UI Tabs 1.7.2"  file which is for showing image slider on the same parent page,
Error is  :-
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'add': object is null or undefined.

and while debugging its coming from the below code,

```
    a(window).bind("unload", function () 
    {
                p.lis.add(p.anchors).unbind(".tabs");
                p.lis = p.anchors = p.panels = null
            })
```

as "p.anchors" is coming null, but how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the solution guys, great effort on by "maxchirkov" on weblink http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-32-thickbox-jquery-ui-tabs-conflict.

The issue was from "unload" event conflict in the thickbox and Jquery-UI-tabs scripts.

In the thickbox.compressed.js, I hv changed:-

```
// $("#TB_window").fadeOut("fast", function () { $('#TB_window,#TB_overlay,#TB_HideSelect').trigger("unload").unbind().remove(); });
```

above code to :-

```
$("#TB_window").fadeOut("fast", function () { $('#TB_window,#TB_overlay,#TB_HideSelect').unload("#TB_ajaxContent").unbind().remove(); });
```

and its working now.